# Firebase AppCheck: Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-app-check

After setting up AppCheck for my iOS app using DeviceCheck and App Attest, I'm getting errors like the following in the Xcode console when running the simulator or on an actual iPhone.

`10.10.0 - [FirebaseAuth][I-AUT000018] Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: Error Domain=com.firebase.appCheck Code=4 "The attestation provider AppAttestProvider is not supported on current platform and OS version." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The attestation provider AppAttestProvider is not supported on current platform and OS version.}`

I figured that maybe I needed to have the app installed through the AppStore, so I built a new version and tested it with Test Flight. I get the same error.

Firebase 10.10.0
iOS 16.5.1(c)
Xcode 14.3
SwiftUI

Comment: Hey, @jeff-g have you found a solution to this problem? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing AppCheck on Simulator you have to use a debug token as real attestation protocol wont work.

Go to Firebase > AppCheck
And create a debug token.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

hello the problem is that you don't enable the Sign-in providers in Authentication on the Firebase website

These are the steps :

go to your project on the Firebase website, and then go to your project overview select "Authentication", and enable the Sign-in provider that you want to be in your project

[image]